# Inverse scaler transform within sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to apply standardization followed by imputation using KNN. Then I want to back transform the values, because I will apply some other transforms that require the original data. Is it possible to do this in scikit-learn pipeline? No matter what I tried, I get an error.

Note: The inverse transform should be done within the pipeline, not when the pipeline has finished.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder, FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ss = StandardScaler()
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=3, add_indicator=False)
ohe = OneHotEncoder()

df_example = pd.DataFrame(data={"num1":[1, 2, 3, np.nan, 6, 6, 9, 4, 5], 
                                "num2":[4, np.nan, 6, 5, 3, 8, 2, 8, 3], 
                                "cat1":['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B']})

list_numeric_vars = ["num1", "num2"]
list_cat_vars = ["cat1"]

pipeline_num = Pipeline([    

    ("standardizer", ss),
    ("imputer", imputer),
    ("standardizer_inverse", FunctionTransformer(ss.inverse_transform))
])

pipeline_cat = Pipeline([    
    ("ohe", ohe),
])


ct = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers = 
        [
            ("pipeline_num", pipeline_num, list_numeric_vars),
            ("pipeline_cat", pipeline_cat, list_cat_vars)
            
        ], 
    remainder ="drop"
    )

ct.fit(df_example) # Error
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since the standard scaler and KNN imputer (mean from n-nearest neighbors) are linear operations, running `standardizer >> imputer >> inverse_standardizer` produces the same results as `imputer` alone.

You can simplify your numeric pipeline as follows:

```py
pipeline_num = Pipeline([
    ("imputer", imputer),
    # Add other processing steps here
])
```

Here's "proof" that the imputer operation alone produces the same results:

```py
df1 = ss.fit_transform(df_example[list_numeric_vars])
df1 = imputer.fit_transform(df1)
df1 = ss.inverse_transform(df1)
print(f'Scale/Impute/Inverse-Scale:\n{df1}\n')

df2 = imputer.fit_transform(df_example[list_numeric_vars])
print(f'Impute Only:\n{df2}\n')
```

Here's the output:

```py
Scale/Impute/Inverse-Scale:
[[1.         4.        ]
 [2.         6.        ]
 [3.         6.        ]
 [3.33333333 5.        ]
 [6.         3.        ]
 [6.         8.        ]
 [9.         2.        ]
 [4.         8.        ]
 [5.         3.        ]]

Impute Only:
[[1.         4.        ]
 [2.         6.        ]
 [3.         6.        ]
 [3.33333333 5.        ]
 [6.         3.        ]
 [6.         8.        ]
 [9.         2.        ]
 [4.         8.        ]
 [5.         3.        ]]
```